# VBA: existing form object not detected?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro (Excel 2010) and a textbox with name CSVExport in the sheet. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export()
  Dim exportRangeStr As String    
  Dim currSheet As Worksheet    

  Set currSheet = Worksheets("Skill Experience")
  exportRangeStr = currSheet.CSVExportRange.Value
  Debug.Print 1
```

When I try to run it I get an error "Compile error: Method or data member not found" with *.CSVExportRange* highlighted. But when I comment that line out and set a breakpoint in the last line I see in the watch window that currSheet **has** the CSVExportRange field and all its data properly stored. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic `Worksheet` class does not have a `CSVExportRange` member. You either need to declare your `currSheet` variable as an Object, or using the specific code name for the worksheet in question (or the relevant interface if you've set one up).